# C# Numeric formatting question

Tags: c#, formatting, numbers

I have these numbers:

```
5.25
10251.35
5
```

and I want them to be formatted with groups and always with 2 decimals ,XX

this is what `.ToString("N2")` does:

```
5,25
10.251,35
5
```

How can i make the **'5'** look like **5,00** too ? 
And for multiple cultures of course (en: 5.0, de: 5,0 ...)

**In fact this question has no sense, N2 should do it at all costs. The problem was in my WebServer.**

Comment: What, no answer from Jn Skeet? Must be on his tea break.

Comment: Bugger, sticky 'O' key there.

Comment: I can't believe you remember me ...

Comment: and you shouldn't be offensive far as i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this working for you:

```
decimal d = 5m;
string formatted = d.ToString("N2");
```

This will use the current culture, but you could specify one:

```
string formatted = d.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But it does not display 12.510,00.  It only displays 12.510

Comment: `12510m.ToString("N2")` returns `12,510.00` for en-US.

Comment: if it does.. something must be very wrong.. cause when i paste this into my code: 12510m.ToString("N2")  it simply prints 12,510

Comment: i set the culture settings for en-US

Comment: OK but if you say that it should output it with decimals then i accept it. There problem must be somewhere else.. thank you

Comment: How about `12510m.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Comment: Well at least that's what the documentation states (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: Yes.. I read it of course. I restarted my WebServer and it suddenly works.. I can't believe that. 
10,251.35
5.00
4.00

Answer (score 2):

.ToString("{0:#,0.00}")

Note: although this uses US grouping & decimal symbols, the result will be locale aware, assuming that either your current user locale is set correctly or you pass a locale into ToString().

Answer (score 0):

IIRC:

```
toString("0:0.00");
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With the format you have (Fixed-point), you should use:

```
.ToString("F2");
```

You have all the format here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: In fact, I'd like to have a combination N with F, not only F2